# Java Exception inside catch block

Tags: java, exception

here is a code:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("path");
    javaClassFun(url,fout);
    fout.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    System.err.println("Invalid URL"+ex);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Input/Output error"+e);
}
```

when i cut the last catch block and paste it after try block it gives unreachable catch block error.
I want to know what is the reason behind this.

Comment: When an `Exception` is thrown, the `catch` block checks whether the thrown exception is an instance of `Exception type` in `catch` block and leaves it inside `catch` block. In your case, the catch block with `IOException` swallow all `IOException` and its subtypes. i.e. `MalformedUrlException`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why is that `MalformedURLException` inherits from `IOException`.

```
try {
    //call some methods that throw IOException's
} catch (IOException e) {
    // This will catch MalformedURLException since it is an IOException
} catch (MalformedURLExceptionn ex) {
    // Will now never be caught! Ah!
}
```

If you want to design catch blocks which properly handle an exception hierarchy, you need to put the super class last and the subclasses which you want to handle individually prior to it. See the example below for how to handle the `IOException` class hierarchy as it pertains to your code.

```
try {
    //call some methods that throw IOException's
} catch (MalformedURLExceptionn ex) {
    // This will catch MalformedURLException 
} catch (IOException e) {
    // This will catch IOException and all other subclasses besides MalformedURLException
}
```

Comment: You should probably explain what that means, and why it produces the behavior that OP is seeing.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Updated with an explanation and solution to the problem that the OP is seeing.